# how to use parameter from json webservice and retrieve json data

Tags: android, json, web-services

I'm developing an android application which will use the webservice which should accept 1 parameter from the user and based on that the value is fetched from DB(sql server 2008) and bind that to android:LISTVIEW.

Without using the parameter my android application is working fine.But when i altered my webserservice to accept parameter and call it in android it is not displaying.

Comment: Whats is your actual issue? i think when u try to call an API and its returns JSON data and u couldn't append that in your list view?

Comment: i got ans from webservice to listview. .but i want that webservice data after passing parameter from user..

Comment: "after passing parameter from user" can u elaborate this?

Comment: Actually  i created json webservice in Asp.net in that webservice i included 1 parameter and list of datas. and also i used that websrvice in android and get value in listview .but i want  to get data from  that webservice by passing parameter.from the user .in android..

Comment: http://java.dzone.com/articles/invoke-webservices-android check this tutorial and it may help you

Comment: i created json webservice.. the above link is related to soap funtion..